# Подключение css

Tags: python, html, css, postgresql, flask

Делаю свои первые попытки в создание "сайта" на python + flask. Требования к дизайну самые минимальные, однако возникла проблема с подключением CSS. Создал файл main.css, прописал в нем

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Однако при попытке подключить его возникает странность: ничего не работает, а vs code предлагает создать новый файл в "\project2020\templates{{ url_for('static', filename='static/css", под именем " main.css') }} " Основной файл (index.html) выглядит так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = ru>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Pulp fiction homepage</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='static/css/main.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <H1>Книжный магазин "pulp fiction"</H1>
        </header>
        <div>
          <a href="catalog.html"> Перейти в каталог</a>
        </div> 
        <div>
            <a target="_blank" href="map.html"> Доставка</a>
          </div> 
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

В чем может быть проблема, как ее исправить и что прочитать чтобы **максимально быстро** запустить это все в связке с postgresSQL и забыть о своей дизайнерской импотенции?

Comment: Так где ты создал файл main.css? Страница ссылается на текущий каталог/static/css/main.css

Comment: @Smithson в \project2020\static\css, делаю все по туториалу

Comment: ./static/css/main.css  >> ./ - текущая директория

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берете и вставляете вместо `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='static/css/main.css') }}">` , это:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**неправельно**: < link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='static/css/main.css') }}">

**правельно**: < link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">

-static

--css-->main.css